# react axois post why my nested product not adding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My api is working and I tested on thunderbold where my parent and child product creating.

here my payload which my backend accept from fontend:

```
 {
      "title": "Parent Product hello world UPDATED123",
      "description": "Description of the Parent Product",
       .... others fileds
      
      
      "child_product": [
        {
          "title": "Child Product",
          "description": "Child Product",
          "orginal_price": 5,
       
          "attributes": [
             "XXL",
              "XXXL"
          ],
          "images": [
             "../image_2023_12_30T13_41_37_062Z.png" ,
             "../image_2023_12_30T13_41_37_062Z.png" 
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

when tying to send the payload from my react no child product is creating.  my code

```
const PublishProduct = async () => {
    try {
      let response;
  
  
        // Make a POST request
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title',Product.title)
        formData.append('description',Product.description)
        formData.append('orginal_price',Product.orginal_price)
        formData.append('orginal_price',Product.orginal_price)
        formData.append('discount',Product.discount)
        formData.append('quantity',Product.quantity)
        formData.append('unit',Product.unit)
        Product.parent_images.map((data)=>{
          formData.append('parent_images',data.image)
        })

        variationProduct.map((data)=>{
          formData.append('child_product[title]',data.title)
          formData.append('child_product[description]',data.description)
          formData.append('child_product[orginal_price]',data.orginal_price)
          formData.append('child_product[orginal_price]',data.orginal_price)
          formData.append('child_product[discount]',data.discount)
          formData.append('child_product[quantity]',data.quantity)
          formData.append('child_product[unit]',data.unit)
          Product.parent_images.map((data)=>{
            formData.append(`images`, data.image);
          })
        })

        response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/product/', formData);
    
  
      // Handle the response as needed
      console.log('Response:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

here is screenshot when sending api request from thunderbold my parent and child product is creating

[image]

Comment: Check the API request in the network tab for post. Your API expects child_product to be array however you aren't creating any array for child_product while appending in FormData